# Python for large graphs

Tags: library, python, graphs, search

I have a large graph consisting of 30 million edges. Currently it is saved as a CSV file of the edges. I would like to run standard graph algorithms like BFS on it. Is there a library in Python for such tasks? Or maybe someone can tell me what I could use for this purpose.

Comment: Personally, I would go for GraphViz. Take a look at [the gallery](https://graphviz.gitlab.io/gallery/)